# Can I port my old C# desktop application on IPad using MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

Can I port my old C# desktop application on IPad using MonoTouch?

Comment: Within limits, anything can be ported to anything. You'll need to be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably re-use any modular logic.

The MonoTouch UI code is completely different than WinForms (or anything else in .NET really) so re-use there is pretty much impossible.

If your application mixed UI and Logic code in the same place, you'll have to pull out the logic and create separate assemblies for them. You can then build your UI (using InterfaceBuilder) and then wire everything up with some new UI code.